# Ruby On Rails - namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, request, syntax-error

could anyone help me with the ROR? I am a beginner and I have brutal problems with namespaces.

Exception is :

No route matches [GET] "/admin"

and routes.rb

```
SimpleCms::Application.routes.draw do

  namespace :admin do
    resources :auth
  end

  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'

end
```

Auth controller is in admin dir and view exist too.
Where is problem? Thx

Answer (score 0):

What url are you trying to hit? `admin` is just a namespace, not an endpoint. The endpoint you've defined will be `/admin/auth`.

Comment: Ou :D true, /admin/auth is good, but how I define root for /<domain>/admin ??

Comment: you could try something like `match "/:domain/admin" => 'Auth#my_action"`, which will route to `AuthController#my_action`, with `domain` in the `params` hash. I don't how many actions you want the `AuthController` to handle, so I can't give you more detail than this right now, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
resources :admin, :controller => "auth"
```

This will match all `admin` routes to the `AuthController`.  You should read the [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use) it is very comprehensive.

You can get a list of all your current routes by running `rake routes` in the terminal.

If I was you I would remove `match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)` from your `routes.rb` as it will enable all HTTP requests to all your controller methods, which you probably don't want.